# как программно поменять цвет фона и текста popup menu?

Tags: android, kotlin, popupmenu

у меня есть popup menu и в зависимости от выбора темы он должен быть разного цвета, но как это сделать? У меня не получилось даже просто поменять его цвет через стили

`

```
private fun showPopup(view: View){
        var popup: PopupMenu? = null
        popup = PopupMenu(this, view)
        val myIntent = Intent(this, aboutActivity::class.java)
        val myHistory = Intent(this, HistoryActivity::class.java)
        popup.inflate(R.menu.menu_main)
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener { item: MenuItem? ->
            when (item!!.itemId){
                R.id.developers -> {
                    myIntent.putExtra("thm", them.toInt())
                    startActivity(myIntent)
                }
                R.id.history -> {
                    myHistory.putExtra("history", ans.toString())
                    myHistory.putExtra("thm", them.toInt())
                    startActivity(myHistory)
                    super.finish()
                }
                R.id.theme -> {
                    dialog_test()
                }
            }
            true
        })
        popup.show()
    }
```

`

Comment: Где здусь в коде меняется цвет? К чему вообще этот кусок кода в вопросе?

Comment: В том месте где указана тема, в папке styles.xml как правило но не факт, в самой теме нужно переопределить стиль popup диалогов. И если темы две, то в каждой теме указать свой. Примерно так

Comment: @Романыч, дело говорит! Но если сильно нужно поментя какие-то параметры программно, можно это сделать через контекст, вы когда менюхе передаёте контекс, в нём нужно достать тему и изменить ей нужны вам параметры

Comment: @Valeriy как именно можно изменить параметры, например фон popup?